# Verb number when subject is percent

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, percentages

I have just seen some answers here to the effect that

> Ten percent of the pie *is* mine

is correct.

This seems rather odd to me.  Ten percent is a plural subject, so why
should it have a singular verb.

Note that, grammatically, *of the pie* is subordinate to *percent* and
should be inessential; that is, it should be possible to remove it
without affecting the grammaticality of the sentence.

My question is not whether the example sentence is correct (that is the
question of which this is alledgedly a duplicate) but *why* it is
considered correct -- given my grammatical objection -- and *for how
long* it has been.  I would guess that this is a relatively new
phenomenon and that in the good old days, there was no special rule for
this case, such that the verb would have had to be *are.*

References please.

---

Please do not mark this question as a duplicate without reading it.
How is it possible to mistake a question asking *why* something is
considered correct and *for how long* with one asking *what is correct?*

Comment: I don't think you'll find references, because the use of percentages hasn't been common enough for long enough. To me *ten percent of the pie* is singular, even though the quantifier contains the number ten. I'm not sure the quantifier is really greater than one anyway - it only seems that way if you ignore *percent* or try to read *percent* as it it involves breaking the pie down into separate pieces and counting them out, rather than being merely numerical.

Comment: @Minty, I think a distinction should be made between grammatical and
mathematical number.  Ten thirds are still _ten_ of something; that they
are also less than one of something else is grammatically irrelevant.

Comment: But not ten of the thing that is the subject, so the subject does not have a ten-ness. It's not like *ten of the pies*. Here I'm not sure the subject is even countable, but if it is I think the number has to 0.1.

Comment: @Minty, that doesn't matter though.  The grammatical subject is _Ten percent (of the pie)_ the parenthesized bit is internal to it and should not affect the number of the expression.  Nor should it matter what a percent is.  All that matters is that there are ten of them.

Comment: That's where we differ, I think - I don't think there are ten of the units of the subject. This is a partitive construction meaning *some of the pie*, so if it can be said to have any units at all, the number of them has to be less than 1. Even if the sentence was *10% of the pies were laced with arsenic*, the countable units would be pies, not hundredths of pies. If I say *two fifths of people don't regard the so-called pot pie as a proper pie at all*, the relevant unit is people, not fifths of people.

Comment: @Minty, you are writing as if _the pie_ were the subject; it is not.

Comment: Would you say '0.2 of the pie are eaten'? 'Two-thirds of the pie are eaten'? 'A dozen pie was eaten'? 'Fish and chips are my favourite meal'? At some stage, **everyone** bows to notional rather than strictly formulaic agreement (sometimes called unhelpfully 'grammatical agreement'). It's agreed by many people that '90% of the people are right-handed' and '78% of the air is nitrogen' are the best usages (though many disagree over say 'England was soon bowled out' or 'England were soon bowled out'). Few would argue that any of the notional choices are actually 'wrong'.

Comment: I'm not - I said in my first comment that the subject was *ten percent of the pie*. If the subject was *pie*, obviously that would be singular.

Comment: @Minty, well, then you are using _subject_ in two different ways; that's confusing.

Comment: I was reaching for a term that describes the units in which the subject would be counted. I did better on my second attempt...

Comment: @Minty, and now, by _subject,_ you mean the pie??

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I do think _Two thirds of the pie are eaten_ sounds
right.  Don't you?  _Two thirds of the pie_ is _eaten_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, all right, I admit that _78% of the air are nitrogen_ sounds very odd.  That's helpful, thanks.

Comment: No, I mean that the subject is *two-thirds of the pie*, as I originally said. The point is that where you have a quantifier which is a fraction of some kind - be it so many percent or so many fifths or whatever - the denominator of that fraction is not necessarily or even normally the unit in which we count the subject, and in any event, a partitive will always take the singular even if it has a quantifier with a numerator greater than one.

Comment: @Minty, this is not so much an explanation as a restatement of the problem.  You speak of the ''partitive'' ''taking'' a singular, but it is not clear how that is grammatically possible or relevant.  In fact, describing _of the pie_ as _partitive_ suggests that it is subordinate to the subject, which is _ten percent._

Comment: It may make more sense if you understand ***10%*** to be a shortening of ***a 10% portion.***

Comment: The subject isn't *ten percent* - it's *ten percent of the pie*. *ten percent* really is subordinate, because it is a quantifier. To determine whether the whole subject is singular or plural, you ask how many pies there are. If the answer is that there is only part of a pie, that is partitive. If more than 1, plural - if exactly 1, singular. You are trying to read *ten* as the quantifier and *percent* as the thing quantified (or part of it), as in *I cut that pie into quarters last night and when I came down this morning two quarters were gone*...

Comment: ... I'm not sure that's even possible with *percent*, but supposing it is, you have to make a judgment about whether the speaker is talking about pie and using *ten percent* as a quantifier, or talking about *percent of the pie* and using *ten* as the quantifier. IOW is the message about the pie, with *percent* just a convenient way of quantifying it, or is the speaker's interest really in percents of the pie?

Comment: @Minty, I don't care about intersts but grammar, and in classical grammar the subject is _ten percent._

Comment: @AndrewLeach, you have marked as duplicate of a question I alluded to.  Please read my question.

Comment: I did read it. But you haven't **linked to the other question** and said why it doesn't answer your question. You also seem to have founded your question on a false premise, namely that *ten percent* is "ten percents" and must be plural. It isn't; it's a single lump of something. Even if it's "ten percent of the population", you are likely considering it as a single entity; and if not, you are actually considering each person within that ten percent individually, **then** the verb might be plural. But that doesn't happen very often at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, there is a difference between asking _how is it_ and asking _why_ and _for how long._  Those answers have no argumentation/explanation and no references.

Comment: The problem is that *why is it so?* is founded on a false premise, because it is not so, as the other question demonstrates.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I think you are wrong.  In any case, my question, whether it is ill-founded or not, is different from the other one, which does not ''demonstrate'' anything.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, what is in your opinion the subject of the sentence?

Comment: The subject of the sentence is "ten percent of the pie" which is an amount. It's exactly analogous to "all the pie" or "half the pie". It's even treated as singular if you write "ten hundredths of the pie" -- **unless** each hundredth is a separate slice. Since you're then counting ten **slices,** that would legitimately be plural.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, no, it is analogous to _all OF the pie is gone,_ where the subject is _all._

Comment: OK, if you like. *All* (or *half* in "half **of** the pie) is still treated as **singular**.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, the operative phrase being _treated as._  The question was: has it always been treated thus (_for how long_), given that it _is_ not.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that 'ten percent' is the subject here. Plural or singular - that must agree with the object ('pie') of the preposition 'of', following 'ten percent', to provide subject and verb agreement:

https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/singular-vs-plural/subject-and-verb-agreement-with-collective-nouns/

> ***Example:*** Twelve percent of the building **has/have** been renovated. The subject is twelve percent, which will be either singular or plural
>   depending on the object of the preposition that follows. In this
>   sentence, the object of the preposition is **building**, which is always
>   **singular**. So the correct answer is **has**.

'Pie' is singular, so is 'ten percent' in this particular sentence.

Comment: It is incredible to me that _ten <noun>_ should ever be singular.  Something singular is something whose number is one.  Something whose number is 10 is not something whose number is 1.

Comment: https://www.englishgrammar.org/object-preposition/

Comment: (a) 'Prepositional object' _is_ standard. However,  the prepositional phrase is as much part of the subject here as is 'concerned' in 'The people concerned  attended a meeting at the Parish Hall.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, is _object_ the only standard term here?

Comment: [No (as per ParentingPatch](https://parentingpatch.com/prepositional-complement-english-grammar/), say) ... but according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prepositional+object%2Cprepositional+complement&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprepositional%20object%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprepositional%20complement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cprepositional%20object%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprepositional%20complement%3B%2Cc0) it's the commonest by a factor of about 2.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, ok.  btw, in this situation i'm not notified without an @

Comment: @Toothrot Sorry; getting two hotlinks into a 'comment' isn't easy, and other considerations end up on the back-burner. The first comment _was_ intended for Alex, though, the first part as an encouragement, but the second as a warning that 'grammarbook' isn't always reliable.